# How to create a Fixed or Sticky footer and have work on my site

Tags: html, css, footer, fixed, sticky

I am trying to achieve the sticky or fixed footer on our website.

Here is a link to one of the pages that I'm trying to get it to work on.

http://www.fabricatorsunlimited.com/test/quartzcare.html

When I put the `<div class="wrapper">` right after the `</head>` it gets this giant space after the navigation bar and the carousel.

I can post code if necessary..

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to remove .line class from <footer>?

Comment: That moved the footer down! Thank you! Is there a way that I can make the "push" class fill the space to the footer with the background color?

Comment: I put everything in an answer.

Comment: `<a href="index.html"><div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></a></div>` - wrong nesting of tags here. Please check your HTML via the W3C validator before asking for help.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it. That's how you thank people helping you around here.

Comment: I thought it solved my problem but then it causes a new problem, as I explained below.

Answer (score 0):

To move the footer down: remove le class .line from `<footer>` tag.

To "push" class fill the space to the footer with the background color:
add `height: 100%` to `<section>` tag and to the div with .push class (thus removing the height: 85px).

Comment: Here is what I have for that portion of the CSS

.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -85px;}
 
.footer, .push {
 height: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 clear: both;} 

It didn't seem to work, I uploaded it again to the web so the changes are current..

Comment: try section{ height: 100%;}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this at footer class, it will stick footer to the bottom.

```
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the footer element separate from the section as now the footer is a child of a section element. If you put your element outside this will resolve your issue.

Let me put some of your code here.

```
<header>
....    
</header>
<section>
    <div class="line">
    <div class="margin">
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="footer">
<footer>
    <div class="box">....</div>
</footer>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**
I have created a small [Snippet](http://snippi.com/s/1emgk6q) from your html.